# Entity Framework 6 SaveChanges causes unique constraint exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm getting a unique constraint violation when trying to do `SaveChanges()` on my EF.

There are two columns, `ID` and `Order`.  The unique constraint is on those two columns.

I'm updating the order (swapping two of the values).

However, when I do `SaveChanges()` I get a `DBUpdateExcception` saying I've violated the unique constraint - but I haven't!  **I've just swapped the order**.

```
Name | ID | Order
BH   | 49 | 1
JK   | 49 | 2
```

So in code, it now looks like this (and I've checked the EF in the debugger)

```
Name | ID | Order
BH   | 49 | 2
JK   | 49 | 1
```

As I said though, when I do `SaveChanges()` I get an exception.

I don't know if there is a problem with my model in visual studio 2015 (have to set a property or something to allow updates?).  The problem seems to me to be that "it" isn't doing the update correctly.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Post your actual C# code, like models and save changes

Comment: If I correctly understood it's not possible. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e483f98e-085b-46ba-b748-6e1614558efc/updating-the-entity-primary-key?forum=adodotnetentityframework). As stated in answer there it's possible to delete old entity and readd new, but it depends on your DB relations structure.

Comment: @CallumLinington Sorry, I didn't have access to my code at the time of posting - had to try and do it during lunch and from memory.

Comment: @ieaglle Thanks for the link. Please note that in my case, I'm **not** dealing with the PK.

Comment: Can't you just add an arbitrary PK?

Comment: @CallumLinington I actually do have a primary key, I just haven't included it in my example (to keep things simple).

Comment: Well having a primary key will always mean you have a unique entry... I guess we'll have to wait for the real code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EntityFramework updates one row at a time.
So by switching the `Order` value of the two objects and calling `SaveChanges()` It first fires something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET [Order] = 2 WHERE [TABLENAME].[ID] = 49 AND [TABLENAME].[Order] = 1
```

If this update would be executed, you would have two rows in the table with the same values in the unique constraint. This is why you get the error.

Comment: That's what I feared. So is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? I can't be the first person who's needed to update a value that is part of a unique constraint before???  I don't imagine it's possible to disable constraints on the DB temporarily via code...